# Correlation matrix between stocks problem, data not passed correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing a correlation matrix between FANG stocks but at the very last part something is not working in my returns. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as fyf

stocks = 'FB AMZN NFLX GOOG'

stocks = stocks.split()

data = fyf.data.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start ='2020-06-01', end = '2020-06-15')['Close']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

returns = pd.DataFrame()
for stock in data:
    if stock not in data: 
        returns[stock] = np.log(data[stock]).diff()
        
returns = returns[1:]
returns.corr()
```

I used `returns.head()` to see if it even made the table but it was not, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: the if condition should not be `if stock not in returns`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are cancelling each other:

```py
for stock in data:
    if stock not in data:
        ...
```

First you iterate over stocks that are inside `data`, and then you test if they are not in `data`. Any stock provided by the for loop will necessarily test negative on your if condition.